# running 2 infinite loops at the same time

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop, sh

is there a way to run `RFSniffer` and `./test2.sh` without having to break?

```
trap './test2.sh' SIGINT
sudo sh -c ./433Utils/RPi_utils/RFSniffer 2>&1 | tee /home/pi/output.txt
```

this is my while loop as `./test2.sh`

```
while read line
do
  if [[ $line =~ "Received 5592512" ]]; then
     echo "Button A was pushed"
  elif [[ $line =~ "Received 5592368" ]]; then
     echo "Button B was pushed"
  elif [[ $line =~ "Received 5592332" ]]; then
     echo "Button C was pushed"
  elif [[ $line =~ "Received 5592323" ]]; then
     echo "Button D was pushed"
  fi
done < output.txt
```

Comment: You really should've googled this one.
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I have read it, but I am not sure if I am even writing this correct to begin with.

Comment: @ffledgling I am not sure where to put my command that writes to the file within the while loop

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#line-115

Comment: Have you considered using a named pipe instead of the output.txt file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/449132/why-use-a-named-pipe-instead-of-a-file

Comment: @redcricket what would be the benefit? it won't use cpu memory? speed?

Comment: @theStripes you seem to have change the question entirely from the original one asked earlier. Can you rephrase what you're really trying to do here?

Comment: @ffledgling I am trying to run functions when I push a button on my remote control. I call `RFSniffer` to listen to the remote control but it is in a constant while loop listening for the remote; and won't let me run the rest of my code. Is there anyway to get around to break `RFSniffer` when a message is received, do a specific function, and then restart `RFSniffer` for another input? I really don't think I need to be writing out to a file and then having to read it in order to run a function.

Comment: @ffledgling I just want to run a function when a button is pushed on my remote, do a specific function, and then keep listening for another input.